# Using Hibernate between different threads,JVMs and servers

Tags: java, hibernate, cluster-analysis, multithreading, terracotta

I'm working on a system which has a 4 modules, each working on its own server and each should be able to clustered.

What I basically need is to have the ability to work on the same entities on the different modules and have them update appropriately when changes occur on different threads,JVMs and servers.

I've heard, mostly as a buzz-word, that terracotta might be a relevant solution for me but I don't really know.

I'd love to hear some recommendations and ideas on how to tackle this issue.
If, by any chance, someone thinks the problem is not well defined I'm open to suggestions.

**EDIT:** It seems like terracotta is the preffered approach and I would appreciate a little guidance with how, in an overview, should I integrate with Terracotta? Which of their solutions is best to the above scenario? Any pitfalls one might have encountered with Terracotta?

Thanks,
Ittai

Comment: Are you saying you essentially want one giant hibernate session for the entire cluster, so that if two modules have loaded 'UserIttai' and one goes 'setUserComment("SO Rocks");' then the other module sees that new value without refreshing from the database?  If so, yes, Terracotta is probably your best, maybe only, option.  (and scary things can happen when many threads share a hibernate session, program carefully.)

Comment: Terracotta should be best in this situation.

Comment: @Affe, yes essentially that's what I'm saying.
Can any of you recommend of a preferred strategy to use Terracotta? Do you know which of the solutions is more appropriate? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

since we are talking about best strategy... look at jboss cache.. (it uses terracotta) & is easily configurable. it can be clustered to great lengths & should provide a proper solution to your problem..

JBoss cache can be found here http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossCacheDownloadsPage  & documentation can be found here http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/2.0.0.GA/tutorial/en/pdf/JBossCache-Tutorial.pdf..
hope this helps.. let me know if you need any more details...

Regards,
Anantha Sharma